# PHP count instances of array items in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

In PHP 7.3:

Given this array of low relevancy keywords...

```
$low_relevancy_keys = array('guitar','bass');
```

and these possible strings...

```
$keywords_db = "red white"; // desired result 0
$keywords_db = "red bass"; // desired result 1
$keywords_db = "red guitar"; // desired result 1
$keywords_db = "bass guitar"; // desired result 2
```

I need to know the number of matches as described above. A tedious way is to convert the string to a new array (`$keywords_db_array`), loop through `$keywords_db_array`, and then loop through `$low_relevancy_keys` while incrementing a count of matches. Is there a more direct method in PHP?

Comment: There is no more direct method in PHP.

Comment: BTW I don't call it *tedious*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you described in your question but using `array_*` functions:

```
echo count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $keywords_db), $low_relevancy_keys));
```

*(note that you can replace `explode` with `preg_split` if you need to be more flexible)*

or using `preg_match_all` *(that returns the number of matches)*:

```
$pattern = '~\b' . implode('\b|\b', $low_relevancy_keys) . '\b~';

echo preg_match_all($pattern, $keywords_db);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/nl7tO)

Comment: array_intersect is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!